# IdHTTP basic authentication access violation

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, indy, idhttp

I'm trying to do a HTTP Authentication with Indy HTTP class. But for some unknown reason I'm getting an Access Violation error in this line:
**IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Username := Username;**

The code stretch is:

```
  IdHTTP1:= TIdHttp.Create(Application);
  IdHTTP1.ConnectTimeout:= 10000;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
  IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication:= true;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Username := Username;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Password := Password;
      try
        IdHTTP1.Get(PbxURL);
        HttpCode := IdHTTP1.ResponseCode;
      except
        on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
          HttpCode := IdHTTP1.ResponseCode;
```

I'm using Delphi 2010, and already tried to do something like:
**IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Username := 'admin';**
but didn't solved the problem...

Comment: When you say "access violation" or "error" or "exception", you need to tell us **what** the error or AV or exception is (the **exact** error message, including any memory addresses or error codes). We can't see your screen from where we are, so if you don't tell us, we don't know. (Based on the limited info you've provided, you're getting an error trying to write to `00000000`, which means there's no object instance created for `IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication`.)

Comment: Okay, first thing is: when i'm running the .exe outside the compiler/debugger, it don't shows me any error, just don't work... but when i'm debugging, I get this error: **Project Project1.exe raised exception class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address 0051AC50 in module 'Project1.exe'. Read of address 00000000'.**

Comment: Just as I said; there's no `Request.Authentication` object instance created. See my answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From a quick check, it appears that there is no `IdHTTP.Request.Authentication` needed (and therefore none is created) when the `Request.BasicAuthentication` is true. You should be using `Request.UserName` and `Request.Password` instead.

```
IdHTTP1:= TIdHttp.Create(Application);
IdHTTP1.ConnectTimeout:= 10000;
IdHTTP1.Request.Clear;
IdHTTP1.Request.BasicAuthentication:= true;
IdHTTP1.Request.UserName := UserName;
IdHTTP1.Request.Password := Password;
```

Comment: It's looking like it working now, but that's something strange, in other application, I have **IdHTTP1.Request.Authentication.Username** and it works properly. And I'm creating same objects in same order than in this project...

Comment: It can't be working with `Request.Authentication.Username` if you're using basic authentication in the other app, if everything else is the same. Are the versions of Indy the same in both apps?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `Request.Authentication` object is not allocated until a request has been sent and an authentication response has been received, then the `OnSelectAuthorization` event is triggered to determine which class type to allocate for the object for subsequent requests..

The only other way the `Request.Authentication` object can be allocated is if you do it manually in your own code before sending a request, such as if you know ahead of time which auth scheme the server uses without sending a request to discover that dynamically.